# Using boost to read a binary file into a std::vector?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I have a function that stores a `std::vector<uchar>` into a binary file, using boost:

```
void vectorWrite(const string& filename, const std::vector<uchar> dataV)
{

    std::ofstream ofs3(filename, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa3(ofs3);
    oa3 << dataV;
    ofs3.close();

}
```

This seems to work fine, but I am having trouble reversing the process.
This code crashes:

```
    std::vector<uchar> vectorRead(const string& filename)
    {
        std::vector<uchar> v2;
        std::ifstream ifs(filename);
        boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ifs);
        ia >> v2;

       return v2;
    }
```

I am then running:

`std::vector<uchar> dataBack = vectorRead("vector.bin");`

Is it not this simple? What am i missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

What i was missing, was *opening the file in binary mode*:

```
std::ifstream ifs(filename);
```

needed to be:

```
std::ifstream ifs(filename, std::ios::binary);
```

So, it becomes

```
std::vector<uchar> vectorRead(const string& filename)
{
    std::vector<uchar> v2;
    std::ifstream ifs(filename, std::ios::binary);
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ifs);
    ia >> v2;

    return v2;
}
```